# What's backquote meaning in upf writed by tcl?

Tags: tcl, cadence, clp

I'm seeing upf src code, but I meet the backquote before create_power_domain. I don't understand what's backquote meaning in follow code.(the code is used by clp)

```
` create_power_domain CORE -elements {.}
```

I have searched in tcl lan, but I couldn't find the explain.

Comment: Backquote is not part of core Tcl, so I assume it is one of the UPF additions - https://www.techdesignforums.com/practice/guides/unified-power-format-upf/ - but I'm not familiar with those, sorry.

Comment: I've never seen backticks in UPF files.   I work with Synopsys tools rather than Cadence tools, but I doubt a backtick is a special Cadence thing.   

Are you sure this isn't a typo that you came across?